# Android Studio - How to set default AVD for XML design viewer

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-virtual-device

I am trying to find if there's a way to set my default AVD to a custom device configuration that I've setup - specifically, when using XML design viewer.

Whenever I open a split view (XML/Design) it is defaulting to Pixel device - however I have a custom device that I would like as the default project wide, so whenever I open an XML I do not have to constantly change it.

[image]